# angular2 router data pass to children but not pass lazyload children

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Question1:
Component oninit function use router.data.subscribe to get data and parent data.

why can get parent data?

I can't find out info at router doc. [angular2 router](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)

Question2:
why can't get root parent data? at app-router.module.ts I defined
*data: {pageTitle: 'youare', test:123213213},*

I can't get data at CrisisListComponent.

app-router.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginPage},
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    data: {pageTitle: 'youare', test:123213213},
    children: [
      {
        path: 'personalcenter',
        loadChildren: 'app/personalcenter/personal-center.module#PersonalCenterModule',
        data: {pageTitle: 'personalcenter'}
      },
      {
        path: 'crisis-center',
        loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule',
       data: { preload: true }
      },
]
```

crisis-center-routing.module.ts

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    data:{you:"are"},
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent,
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
            resolve: {
              crisis: CrisisDetailResolver
            }
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

crisis-list.component.ts

```
    export class CrisisListComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(
        private service: CrisisService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
      ) {}


      ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.subscribe(data=>{
          console.log("asdfsadfsadf"+JSON.stringify(data));
        });
      }

    }
```

**At CrisisListComponent , print log:" asdfsadfsadf{"preload":true,"you":"are"}"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was asked 1 month ago, and seems nobody answer it as I want, and I hope this answer will help people who encounter this problem.
I'm not a native English speaker, sorry about my bad English.

> it works as intended.
> These are the rules of inheriting params and data:
>   1. Resolved data is derived from params. So the rules apply to params and data in the same way.
>   2. An empty-path route inherits its parent's params and data. This is because it cannot have its own params (it's an empty-path route), and, as a result, it often uses its parent's params and data as its own.
>   3. Any route inherits its parent's params and data if the parent is a componentless route. This is because there is no component that can inject the parent's activated route.
>   Nothing else gets inherited.

If you want to get data but not inherit componentless parent, you can use `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.routeConfig`, which get original routes configuration.

```
export class CrisisListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private service: CrisisService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.data) // {you:"are"}
  }
}
```

And if you want to get data from root in CrisisListComponent, just

```
export class CrisisListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private service: CrisisService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.root.snapshot.data) // {pageTitle: 'youare', test:123213213}
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering the the inheritance will continue until a route is found that has 
**a non empty path** or **a component**

Answer (score 1):

some one explain the issue. Angular2/4 router designed the way, If router path is empty, parent router data will pass to children.

Anyone confused the problem, can see detail as below.

[Router data and param should be available to children components](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12767#issuecomment-260493205)

Comment: 1. Resolved data is derived from params. So the rules apply to params and data in the same way.  <br/>
2. An empty-path route inherits its parent's params and data. This is because it cannot have its own params (it's an empty-path route), and, as a result, it often uses its parent's params and data as its own.
3. Any route inherits its parent's params and data if the parent is a componentless route. This is because there is no component that can inject the parent's activated route.